# Is it possible in javascript to inherit properties from another class - rather than an existing object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

For example in PHP if you wanted a class to inherit properties of another class you would reference the parent *class*

```
<?php 

class BaseController {
    // ....
}

class UserController extends BaseController {
    // ....
}
```

However in javascript if you want a new class or object to inherit some properties from another class - it seems you need to assign an - already  instantiated - object of the class you want to inherit from to your objects prototype.

e.g. If you want to *create a brand new object* and access the properties of an existing object:

```
var robot = {
  active : "yes",
  primeDirective : function() {
    console.log("Must kill all humans!");
  }  
};

var bender = Object.create(robot);
bender.primeDirective();  => "Must kill all humans!"
```

or if you have an existing object, you can assign the existing object to prototype using `__proto__`

```
var robot = {
  active : "yes",
  primeDirective : function() {
    console.log("Do a flip!");
  }  
};

var bender = {
  name : "Bender Bending Rodriguez"  
};

bender.__proto__ = robot;
bender.primeDirective(); => "Do a flip!"
```

both these methods require an already created object to inherit properties from, is it possible for a class definition to inherit from another class - similar to the `extends` functionality in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES5 JavaScript the correct way to derive a class is to use `Object.create` passing the base class's `prototype`, not an instance, and then to ensure that all functions are part of that prototype.

```
// a properly formed constructor function
function Robot(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// all functions belong on the prototype
Robot.prototype.primeDirective = function() {
    ...
}

// create derived class
function BendingUnit22(name) {
    Robot.call(this, name);       // invoke superclass constructor
}

// create and attach a new prototype object chained from the base class
BendingUnit22.prototype = Object.create(Robot.prototype);

// and re-attach the constructor
BendingUnit22.prototype.constructor = BendingUnit22;

// add new or overriding functions here
BendingUnit22.prototype.primeDirective = function() {
    ...
}

var bender = new BendingUnit22("Bender Bending Rodriguez");
```

Comment: thanks, Im still trying to get my head around it! but does that mean you would only assign the properties - that you intend to be inherited - to the superclass' `prototype`?

Comment: @user4668401 you wouldn't normally put "plain" properties onto the `prototype` .  If you mean the function properties, though, you'd probably put _all_ of them into the prototype.   There's no hard and fast rule, though.    There's a trade-off if you add "private" functions to `this` over how much memory is consumed.

Comment: thanks, I think I get it now. so anything assigned to the prototype of the superclass is inherited by the subclass, anything not assigned to the super class prototype is essentially private?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a constructor (or an ES6 class) if you want to inherit a little less dynamically.

```
function Robot() {
    this.active = true;
}
Robot.prototype.primeDirective = function() { 
    console.log("Must kill all humans!"); 
};

var bender = new Robot(); // Yey!
```

To create a new inheriting constructor:

```
function HumanoidRobot() {
    Robot.apply(this, arguments);
    this.legs = 2;
}
HumanoidRobot.prototype = Object.create(Robot.prototype);
HumanoidRobot.prototype.constructor = HumanoidRobot;
```

This process becomes a lot easier with ES6 classes, which hide all this ugliness from you!

```
class Robot {
    constructor() {
        this.active = true;
    }
    primeDirective() {
        console.log("Must kill all humans!");
    }
}

class HumanoidRobot extends Robot() {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.legs = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Robot.apply(this, arguments)`, perhaps?  [although personally I prefer to call out that the base class constructor might take different parameters to the derived class]

Comment: ah so is `Robot.apply(this, arguments)` similar to `parent::__construct()` in PHP? sorry for constant references to PHP - its what I know

Comment: Ah I see @Alnitak comments now `Robot.apply(this, arguments) // invoke superclass constructor`

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 kind of inheritance possible in JavaScript.

1. Pseudo Classical (Like the one you are looking for)

   ```
   /**
   * Create a new constructor function, whose prototype is the parent   object's prototype.
   * Set the child's prototype to the newly created constructor function.
   **/

   var extendObj = function (childObj, parentObj) {
      var tmpObj = function () {}
      tmpObj.prototype = parentObj.prototype;
      childObj.prototype = new tmpObj();
      childObj.prototype.constructor = childObj;
   };
   ```

   (https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/4wzuwhqw/)
2. Functional
   (https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/eh7u4pxd/)
3. Prototypal (Object.create)
   (https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/dnjkx8w1/)

Luckily I documented that during a project and captured those JSfiddles.
I hope You will find the required help from these.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in mode for extending classes in Javascript, because it is not a class based but prototype based language.

However, there are many frameworks that implement the 'extend' behaviour, for example in Prototype:

```
 var robot = Class.extend({ ... });
 var bender =  robot.extend({ ... });
```

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

But many other frameworks support the same, for example Underscore _.extend()

http://underscorejs.org/#extend

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
// define the Person Class
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  alert ('I am walking!');
};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert ('hello');
};
// define the Student class
function Student() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Person.call(this);
}

// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

// replace the sayHello method
Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert('hi, I am a student');
}

// add sayGoodBye method
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){
  alert('goodBye');
}

var student1 = new Student();
student1.sayHello();
student1.walk();
student1.sayGoodBye();

// check inheritance
alert(student1 instanceof Person); // true 
alert(student1 instanceof Student); // true
```

Comment: no, this is precisely _not_ what the OP is looking for, because you've _instantiated a `Person`_ to assign that to `Student.prototype`.  It kind-of works, but it's wrong.